# Android and JDK classes

Tags: android, java

I am builting a library which has android and server versions.

The LdapJDK imports javax.naming classes which are not included in android JDK.

Since LdapJDK wouldn't be called on android version of my library, below code works on android phone.

But I am not sure this is a safe way. If some application(eg: webserver) checks all the classes dependency during initialization, my library would cause exceptions.

I would appreciate any comments.

```
public static X509Certificate[] getCertFromLDAP(String url, String dn) throws ASN1Exception, CertificateException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{   
    if (JeTS.getType() == PKIConstants.ANDROID_TYPE)
        return LdapAndroid.getCertFromLDAP(url, dn);
    else 
        return LdapJDK.getCertFromLDAP(url, dn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be safe, create different jars for Android and your server. Exclude anything you don't need/can't use from the Android one.

With that said, as long as you are running on Android 2.x and later, classes are lazy loaded and the code above won't be a problem. Android uses the same pattern to handle backward compatibility, so this is tried and tested.

Comment: Does that mean the server version must be causing problems, as web server might use eager-loading. I should be re-constructing the library. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Java SE always uses lazy class loading. However, your server container (Tomcat, etc.) or framework (Spring, etc.) might do class scanning to check for annotations, etc., so classes might get loaded before they are actually used. This is usually not a problem, because you have all needed libraries. This might not be the case on Android, since it does not support the full Java API.